# jquery validation errorElement div with inner tags

Tags: jquery, validation

Sorry for "cloudy" question, was in hurry and very frustrated.

I'm using jquery validation and want to create tip look a like validation messages.

By providing errorElement I can control in which html tag the error will be contained (by default its label):

$('form').validate({errorElement:"div"});

In order to create tip look alike div, I want to place more html tags in it. I can do that by wrapping the message it self, but i don't like it that way.

So my question is: is there a way to have nested errorElements or is there another attribute that can be used as template?

Thanks, hope that is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your vague question, here is a sample. Suppose the html is as follows:The div is initially empty. It would be populated with a "p" tag if the user does not enter any value in the text box

```
 ​<div id="errorDiv"></div>

 ​<input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
 <button type="button">Submit</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

jquery code:

```
​$(document​).ready(function(){

    $("button").on("click",function(){
        //check if the textbox value is empty. if its empty, then update the innerhtml of the div.
        if($("input[name='name']").val() === ""){
            $("#errorDiv").html("<p>Enter Some Text</p>");
        }
        else {
            $("#errorDiv").html("");
        }
    });        
});​
```